# Assign a Record to a team in dynamics crm 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Assign a record to user is fine but how to assign a record to team i'm unable to find the teamownershipid could you have any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to use the `AssignRequest`, the only change is the `LogicalName` inside the `EntityReference` for the `Assignee`, instead of `systemuser` you need to put `team`.

An example:

```cs
Guid accountId = new Guid("90F8889F-EB95-E781-8417-000C44420CBC");
Guid teamId = new Guid("A8AA28B4-9015-DF11-8062-000E0CA08051");

AssignRequest assignRequest = new AssignRequest
        {
            Assignee = new EntityReference("team", teamId),
            Target = new EntityReference("account", accountId)
        };
service.Execute(assignRequest);
```

Comment: how do i get the teamid. i tried this code to get the teamid.function getOwnerId()
{ 
debugger;
if(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("teamid")!=null && Xrm.Page.getAttribute("teamid").getValue()!=null)
{
var owner= Xrm.Page.getAttribute("teamid").getValue()[0].id;
alert(owner);
}
}

Comment: you want to get the team of the current user? or you have a lookup in your form holding the team?

Comment: i want to assign a record to team.team has group of users.i want to fetch the teamid.

Comment: and where is stored this team? in your form or not?

Comment: it is stored in form only

Comment: which is the entity name that has this lookup in the form? can you add a screenshot of the form?

Comment: sorry for the screen shot it  requires 10 reputations. entityname is team.i'm trying to get the teamid using js function getOwnerId() { debugger; if(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("teamid")!=null && Xrm.Page.getAttribute("teamid").getValue()!=null) { var owner= Xrm.Page.getAttribute("teamid").getValue()[0].id; alert(owner); } }

Comment: but why you need to get the teamid inside a team record? what you will do after with teamid? which record you want to assign after?

Comment: i'm assign record to a team using plugin for that i need to pass teamid.

Comment: inside a plugin you need to use of a fixed teamid, or you need to do a retrievemutiple using some criteria like name="myteam" to get the id value. you can't use javascript inside the plugin

Comment: you posted some code on that how you get that teamid.